# how to clear all inputs in react div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addUser} from "./features/Users";
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userList = useSelector((state) => state.users.value);

  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {" "}
      <div className="addUser">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name..."
          onChange={(event) => {
            setName(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Username..."
          onChange={(event) => {
            setUsername(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            dispatch(
              addUser({
                id: userList[userList.length - 1].id + 1,
                name,
                username,
              })
            );
          }}
        >
          {" "}
          Add User
        </button>
      </div>
);}
```

I am new to react and redux. After clicking the "Add User" button, new User data from inputs in the code will be added to the backend list. I want the values in input sections to be cleared after clicking the "Add User" button, but I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

you need to clear your state after click on submit button. for ex: set function like =>

```
const clearData = {
    setName("")
    setUsername("")
    }
 and pass the func to your onClick event.
onClick={clearData}
```

Comment: I tried this method before, but it's not working.

Comment: So, you should clear your state in your onClick. before dispaching, writie:  setName("");
 setUsername("");

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work perfectly fine.

Just assign `value={name}` and `value={username}` to both input types respectively and when you click `Add User` just `clear` the data in `both` the `states`.

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addUser} from "./features/Users";
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userList = useSelector((state) => state.users.value);

  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {" "}
      <div className="addUser">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name..."
          value={name}
          onChange={(event) => {
            setName(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Username..."
          value={username}
          onChange={(event) => {
            setUsername(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setName("");
            setUsername("");
            dispatch(
              addUser({
                id: userList[userList.length - 1].id + 1,
                name,
                username,
              })
            );
          }}
        >
          {" "}
          Add User
        </button>
      </div>
);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a simple variable with list of form fields and can update the form state with the variable when you needed to clear form data. The below approach comes handy when you need to add additional fields as well.

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addUser} from "./features/Users";

const formFields = { name: '', username: '' };

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userList = useSelector((state) => state.users.value);
  const [params, setParams] = useState(formFields)

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setParams({ ...params }, ...{[name]: value});
  }

  const clearForm = () => setParams(formFields);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="addUser">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name..."
          value={params.name}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Username..."
          value={params.username}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        />
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            dispatch(
              addUser({
                id: userList[userList.length - 1].id + 1,
                ...params
              })
            );
            clearForm();
          }}
        >
          {" "}
          Add User
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
)
}
```